# ASP.NET MVC 3 Toolkits

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, telerik

I am curious what sort of options there are out there for MVC 3 toolkits. For webforms I have always stuck with [Telerik](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CC4QFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.telerik.com%2F&ei=UCl4TofvGcTZiALUnuHIAQ&usg=AFQjCNG5b8wfJMQln6P_TyuSXuPxoEfDkQ&sig2=uhR7-w0pNah2iFxSlrcSbg) controls. Their MVC offerings aren't very many when compared with their webforms offerings. A google search didn't seem to turn up many useful results so I thought I'd see if any devs have any experiences they would like to share.

Anyone have any experience with other useful toolkits that speed up MVC 3 development?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ASP.NET MVC is much younger than classic WebForms so it is normal that there aren't as many toolkits. Personally I use [MvcContrib](http://mvccontrib.codeplex.com/). In addition to server side components I also like client side jQuery plugins. jQuery UI has some pretty nifty controls which are not specific to .NET MVC but could be used in any web application.

Answer (score 3):

Because MVC allows much more control over the HTML, most users find javascript toolkits to be a lot better than serverside toolkits.  jQueryUI, knockout.js, etc..

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative I would suggest DevExpress libraries. I use them, but only for advanced grids usage in backoffice apps, but they really speed up my development in these scenarios.
In frontend apps I never need to implement something so heavy (and ugly as per html code imo) compared to what you can obtain with modern JS toolkit. (I know, a bunch o lines more that you have to write, but it's worth it imo)

Answer (score 0):

You can also look at: [Devexpress ASP.NET MVC Extensions](http://mvc.devexpress.com/)

> **DevExpress ASP.NET MVC Extensions** utilize the jQuery JavaScript library shipping with ASP.NET MVC. Our extensions produce native ASP.NET MVC rendering via an extension to the HtmlHelper class, support the separation of concerns paradigm, and maintain ease of testing practices.